# What is the name of the style this knight is in?

Tags: pieces, identify-this

My grown kid is looking for a chess set of his own. In that process I got curious what style the set I inherited from my grandfather is in. It is most likely bought in Europe in the period 1930-1950. The pieces are weighed.

My guess would be a kind of Staunton but none of those sets we saw in a chess store today looked like this.

Anyone know?

[image]

[image: the whole set]

Comment: I've seen exactly the same style in my chess club, so it is an ubiquituous format.

Comment: It might be a Lardy Knight. They usually have a closed mouth, but some of them are open like this, and the knights in a Lardy Chess Set tend to have the simpler style like this in comparison to a Staunton set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I've found some convincing enough images to solidify my comment as an answer. I don't see anything that looks exactly the same, but it looks very much like a knight from a Lardy chess set.

[Here's an Ebay listing](https://web.archive.org/save/https://www.ebay.com/itm/266209334204) for a similar looking set. Some of the details are a bit different (e.g. the eyes are rounded rather than triangular, and the mouth is cut slightly differently), but the overall form of the knight is almost identical.

It also appears quite similar to the [LARDY CLUB SET listing on the Chess Museum website](http://www.chess-museum.com/lardy.html#:%7E:text=Lardy%20was%20an%20important%20french,which%20closed%20shop%20in%201992.).

Comment: I had the set out (added a photo) and it looks like the proto-lardys are very close indeed!